# Safari prints extra pages

Tags: php, safari, dpi, ppi

I am working on a site where user can print Quiz or Flashcards. Print functionality is working fine on all browsers (IE9, Firefox, Chrome) except Safari. On Safari, when user prints any quiz, extra blank pages are getting printed. I have found out that the logic for calculating pixel to point ratio is creating an issue. Here is the sample of my code.

```
function getHeight(elem) {

var elem_height = 0;
if (typeof elem.innerHeight != 'undefined') {
elem_height = elem.innerHeight;
} else {
elem_height = elem.clientHeight;
    }

return parseInt(elem_height);
} 

var dpiBoxHeight = getHeight(document.getElementById('dpiBox'));
if (dpiBoxHeight < 1) dpiBoxHeight = 96;            
var pixelPointRatio = 72 / dpiBoxHeight;
```

'dpiBox' is an empty div and in CSS we have defined the deafult height as 1 inch.

The value 72 represents points per inch. In safari, I am getting 'dpiBoxHeight' as 96.

If I change, the points per inch Value to above 85 OR change the 'dpiBoxHeight' to less than 85. No blank pages get printed. But, this increases the number of overall printed pages.

Please suggest if you have a solution/workaround which can be used to prevent blank pages getting printed on Safari and is compatible on all the browsers

Thanks in advance,
Neha

Comment: you can check the value and add a display:none to the css

Comment: What other CSS rules, if any, do you have applied to dpiBox?